# DataTable and PDFMake

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, datatables

i want to add some data in div when exporting using datatable pdf button.
How to add div when exporting to pdf?
and i want to ask why my first row header doest show up when i export it

this is my script for datatable

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#globaldatatable').DataTable({
                scrollX: '100%',
                scrollY: 400,
                iDisplayLength: '100',
            ordering: false,
            bPaginate: false,
            sDom: '<"row"<"col-sm-6"B><"col-sm-6">>' + '<"row"<"col-sm-12"<"table-responsive"t>>>' + '<"row"<"col-sm-5"><"col-sm-7">>',
            buttons: {
                buttons: [
                    {   extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> PDF',
                        className: 'excelButton',
                        orientation: 'landscape',
                        title: 'Laporan Detail Karyawan',
                        pageSize: 'A4'
                    },
                    {   extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> EXCEL',
                        className: 'excelButton',
                        title: 'Laporan Detail Karyawan',
                        message: $('#printed').text()
                    }],
                dom: {
                    container: {
                        className: 'dt-buttons'
                    },
                    button: {
                        className: 'btn btn-default'
                    }
                }
            },
            "columnDefs": [ { "width": "5%", "targets": 0 } ]
        });
    });
```

this is my thead and the first row in here doest show up when i export it.

```
<thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="3">
                                    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Saldo Awal</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Terima</th>
                                    <th>Rata</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Keluar</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Saldo Akhir</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Kode Brg</th>
                                    <th>Nama Brg</th>
                                    <th>Satuan</th>
                                    <th>Qty</th>
                                    <th>Nominal</th>
                                    <th>Qty</th>
                                    <th>Nominal</th>
                                    <th>Rata</th>
                                    <th>Qty</th>
                                    <th>Nominal</th>
                                    <th>Qty</th>
                                    <th>Nominal</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
```

this one doest show up when i print it

```
<tr>
                                    <th colspan="3">
                                    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Saldo Awal</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Terima</th>
                                    <th>Rata</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Keluar</th>
                                    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Saldo Akhir</th>
                                </tr>
```

please helpp